# what are texcoord tags in mesh.xml file in Ogrexml format?

Tags: blender, materials, ogre, texture-atlas

I exported a 3d model from blender 2.79 and using ogrexml import/export plugin.
but the texture will crash and UV map not working in that format.
I made the model by four parts head-body-hands-shoes and they have 4 material and 4 textures, so I made a texture atlas for it and join them in a mesh to More optimization.
I think removing other UV maps has a problem because when I check the model.mesh.xml in a note editor and every vertex has 3 texture coordinate tags and I compared it with a normal correct model that looks good in the blender and in ogrexml format, it has one texcoord tag inside of vertex tag.
1-what are texcoord tags? are they using for UV maps in ogrexml format?
2-how can I clear blend files from other unused uvMaps to avoid exporting them with the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I found the problem.

1-it seems the texcoord tag is using to determine the UV map of texture.
2-an option in the data tab of blender is used to keep and show UV maps, from there I deleted unused uvMap and it works correctly.

[image: uvmaps in blender]

Comment: You might want to come back and mark this as the accepted answer :)